# Receiving 404 when uploading file larger than 10kb

Tags: uploads, 404-error, https, nginx, php.ini

I built a file upload form using AJAX code that runs perfectly on my localhost (xampp/apache). I can upload files as large as 256MB. Using HTTP.

However, when I upload this code to my nginx server on aws ec2 I get a 404 when trying to upload any file larger the 10KB (yes that is a K).  I'm using HTTPS.

I thought that maybe the php.ini settings were incorrect so I added this code to the file upload form.

```
<script>
    console.log("max_execution_time = <?php echo(ini_get('max_execution_time')); ?>");
    console.log("max_input_time = <?php echo ini_get('max_input_time'); ?>");
    console.log("memory_limit = <?php echo ini_get('memory_limit'); ?>");
    console.log("post_max_size = <?php echo ini_get('post_max_size'); ?>");
    console.log("file_uploads = <?php echo ini_get('file_uploads'); ?>");
    console.log("upload_max_filesize = <?php echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize'); ?>");
    console.log("max_file_uploads = <?php echo ini_get('max_file_uploads'); ?>");
    console.log("default_socket_timeout = <?php echo ini_get('default_socket_timeout'); ?>");
</script>
```

I get this console output.

Note the 0 followed by "File upload success".  Here 0 is the file error code i.e. `$_FILES['ninja_file']['error']`

The two files I uploaded in this case were 9KB.

When you see the `Post ... 404 ()` at the bottom that was due to me trying to upload a 22KB file.

[image]

In nginx.conf I set

```
client_max_body_size 0;
```

Setting size to 0 disables checking of client request body size per the docs http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

Technology:

- Wordpress 4.7
- PHP 7.0
- NGINX 1.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the nginx error.log (based on nginx.conf error_log location).

```
$ sudo nano /path/to/nginx/error.log
```

There is a "permission denied" error on `/var/lib/nginx`. This happened because I changed the `user` setting in nginx.conf from

```
user nginx;
```

to something else.  In this case,

```
user iam;
```

**Solution:**

Check the current user and group ownership on /var/lib/nginx.

```
$ ls -ld /var/lib/nginx
drwx------ 3 nginx nginx 4096 Aug  5 00:05 /var/lib/nginx
```

This tells you that a possibly non-existent user and group named `nginx` owns this folder. This prevents file uploading.

Change the folder ownership to the user defined in nginx.conf in this case `iam` (sudo may not be required).

```
$ sudo chown -Rf iam:iam /var/lib/nginx
```

Verify that it actually changed.

```
$ ls -ld /var/lib/nginx
drwx------ 3 iam iam 4096 Aug  5 00:05 /var/lib/nginx
```

The permission denied error should now go away. Check the error.log (based on nginx.conf error_log location).

```
$ sudo nano /path/to/nginx/error.log
```

If that doesn't work you might need to reload nginx and php-fpm.

```
$ sudo service nginx reload
$ sudo service php-fpm reload
```

Comment: why didn't it affect files less than 10kb?